# InputStream in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Consider the following code snippet:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
        byte[] buffer= new byte[256];
        file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
        //...
}
```

The `InputStream` command does not work in ASP.NET Core MVC.

☝The inputstream in the asp.net mvc core is no longer supported, there seems to be an alternative to it. I'm looking for itlease guide me

Comment: How does it not work...whats it doing or...not doing?

Comment: The inputstream in the asp.net mvc core is no longer supported, there seems to be an alternative to it. I'm looking for it

Comment: Please expand the question to include the additional direction you've provided in the comments.  Users who can help you out won't necessarily explore the comments to understand your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase` has been replaced by `IFormFile` in `ASP.NET Core`.
See the documentation about [file uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Your controller action method should accept an `IFormFile` instance.

```cs
public ActionResult Upload (IFormFile file)
```

`IFormFile` provides the methods below to access its `Stream`.

```cs
public interface IFormFile
{
    Stream OpenReadStream();

    void CopyTo(Stream target);

    Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    // Remaining members
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the signature of the method has to be changed, because `HttpPostedFileBase` is not supported on NetCore. Instead, IFormFile was introduced.

your method signature should look like this `public ActionResult Upload (IFormFile file)`

To Solve the problem, you can help yourself with an auxiliary function as it is shown bellow:

```
public ActionResult Upload (IFormFile file)
{
    byte[] buffer= new byte[file.Length];
    var resultInBytes= ConvertToBytes(file);
    Array.Copy(resultInBytes,buffer,resultInBytes.Length);

    return Ok(buffer);

}

private byte[] ConvertToBytes(IFormFile image)
{
   using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
     image.OpenReadStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
      return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```